# Add element to Observable<Object[]> variable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to add element to a list in observable, this isn't working well, when I call .pipe(map... this iterate twice, and add element twice.

The observable list:

```
profesionales$: Observable<Profesional[]>;
```

The function for add element:

```
 this.profesionales$ = this.profesionales$.pipe(map(profesionales => {
     return [...profesionales, profesional];
 }));
```

The last 'profesional' in [...profesionales, profesional] is the element for add to the list.

Thanks.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, please create a [MCVE]

Comment: What pipe does is ables you to modify the stream. Map on this stream allows you to modify the value which stream emits into observer which is subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest not to use an Observable for it, instead, you should use a BehaviorSubject and use it like this:

```
profesionales$: BehaviorSubject<Profesional[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Profesional[]>([]);
```

then to add an element:

```
this.profesionales$.next([...this.profesionales$.getValue(), newProfesional])
```

Comment: I need to use an Observable, because I'm getting the data of 'profesionales$' via service http, that returns an Observable.

Comment: can you add this piece of code also, to see it in context

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs `.mergeMap` and `of` to add to an observable.

```
let profesional = { id: 1, name: "some example profesional" };

this.profesionales$ = this.http
    .get<Profesional[]>("some_url")
    .pipe(mergeMap(v => of(v.concat(profesional));
```

Note: I used an `http` call as an example Observable as I'm not sure of your implementation. This is also useful --> [learn rxjs docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Comment: It works as my code. Is adding the item twice, because is entering twice in mergeMap, adding twice the item to the list.

Comment: Where is your original `profesional$` observable coming from?